# Updating a contract variable and testing with truffle

Tags: solidity

I have the following contract, made extremely simply:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract Test {
  bool completed;

  function Test() {
    completed = false;
  }

  function setCompleted() public {
    completed = true;
  }

  function getCompleted() public view returns (bool) {
    return completed;
  }
}
```

And I am testing it in javascript like so:

```
var Test = artifacts.require("./Test.sol");

contract('Test Contract', function(accounts) {
  it("should set and get completed", function() {
    var TestContract

    return Test.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      TestContract = instance

      return TestContract.getCompleted.call()
        .then(function(result) {
          console.log(result, 'should be false');
          return TestContract.setCompleted.call()
        })
        .then(function() {
          return TestContract.getCompleted.call()
        }).then(function(result) {
          console.log(result, 'should be true');
        })
    })
  })
})
```

Shouldn't the call to the setCompleted function update the contract's variable? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calls don't change the contract state over the network, transactions do that.

On another note, you doon't need the function `getCompleted`, solidity creates a getter function for every public variable automatically

Comment: How would you call the getter function with web3js?

Comment: `TestContract.completed.call()` should work